# Save as on file server grayed out

Tags: windows, active-directory, cluster, file-server

When I try to save a file on my Windows fileserver (a failover cluster with 2 nodes), the window is locked and it's not possible to navigate through the folders, and it's not possible to save files in the actual folder.

The only way is to press the "ESC" key, and at that point it is possible to navigate and save files.

Below a screenshot that hopefully explains my issue:

[image: my error]

Answer (score 0):

You first need to choose one of the network shares, or some other drive. You can't save anything directly to `\\fileserver` as that refers to the server itself and not any particular share.

Comment: Yes, i know. The problem Is that of i don't Press esc Button i can't navigate through folders.

Comment: It looks like the application has somehow died. Do you see this in any app?

Comment: in each "save as" window on windows